# Sending JSON from Client to Node.js webserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, rest

**Good evening everybody!**

How can I send data (JSON-formated) from my JavaScript client to my Node.js webserver and how it works in the other direction with using restful webservices?

I am a beginner in node.js and I would learn this great server language, I already searched some time in the internet to solve my problem, but I found nothing.. I found the framework restify.js but I dont exactly understand how I use it.

My idea: A user insert some data in input fields. With jQuery I read the values from the input fields and save it in variables. Now I create a JSON-Object and fill it with the dates from the user inputs(variables). At the next step I use a restful webservice and send the JSON-Object to my node.js-Webserver. At my server-node.js I recieve the dates with restify and send a success text back to the client, also with restify.

How can this work, how can I program this? I am also open for other ideas for example other frameworks if they are easier or better to use, however.

I would be very grateful for all help and please excuse my bad english,
Nico :)

Answer (score -1):

I use `express` for request handling like this :

```
app.route('/date')
    .get(function (req ,res) {
    res.render('html_codes'); // i use ejs for render html files
})
    .post(function(req ,res){
    console.log(req.body); // data you send from client to server    
    });
```

And in your form in client side you need some thing like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        username : <input type="text" name="username" />
        password : <input type="password" name="password" />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It's a very simple example and you should use `AJAX` and other things for an effective web pages but this is the basic understanding of sending requests to server.I hope this could help you.

you can just send data from your forms and don't render them like this(it's just for testing).for this part you need to change action in your form html tag from `action=""` to `action="http://your_ip_address/date"`

UPDATE :

some userfull links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/356975/A-simple-log-server-using-express-nodejs-and-mongo

http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I have some questions: first, where do you parse the dates to an JSON object? and second at the node.js webserver in which variable exactly are the dates from the client stored?

Comment: 1-this data send to server and you receive that as an JSON object.I think this data send in standard form and in express middlewares functions this data parse to json.(I'm not sure about where exactly this date parse).

Comment: 2-In this code NO,but you can easily store it in databases,like `MongoDB` and etc.

Comment: and how would it work, if I would save this dates for example in a mySQL database? 

and thank you for your help :)

Comment: I already tried your code and console.log(req.body) always returns "undefined" in the console..

Comment: It's just a peace of code in `node express` codes, you need a generate an express project and add this to your code ,It's better for you to first study about how websites work and node.js express and etc ,then write codes.

Comment: Do you add `body-parser` to your express configs?

Comment: can you give me a good website where I can learn those things?

How do I add body-parser to my configs?

Comment: I add update, and for more information you can use `google.com`.